# Java FX8 TreeTableColumn Sorting

Tags: javafx-8, treetableview

I created a table in my JavaFX application using `TreeTableView`, and `TreeTableColumn` to specify its columns.

By default, the columns in table are clickable and will sort data in the table whenever the column header is clicked.

I need move to another `Scene` whenever user clicks on a row of the table. So I create a `ChangeListener` object and add it to the `selectedItemProperty` of my table.

My program works fine. But there is a little fault that I've no idea how to fix it.

Everytime I click on the column header to sort data (as I mentioned above), the table sorts the data, but then selects the very first row of the sorted data automatically. Therefore, the `ChangeListener` occurs, and moves to a new `Scene`.

Anyway to prevent the program from selecting the first row of table when clicking on the column headers to sort data?

Please help me.

Edit: This is my code to add the `ChangeListener`:

```
    table.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue observable, Object oldValue, Object newValue) {
        TreeItem<TableModel> selected_item = (TreeItem<TableModel>) newValue;
        if(selected_item != null) {
            //Go to a new scene
            ....        
        }   
    }
    });
```

By the way, I use the default `TreeTableColumn` sorting, I didn't add any code. Just use the default.

Comment: Post your code.

Answer (score 0):

You want to react to clicks on the rows not on selection changes. Therefore you should use a custom `rowFactory` to register listeners on the rows:

```
table.setRowFactory(t -> {
    TreeTableRow<TableModel> ttr = new TreeTableRow<>();
    ttr.setOnMouseClicked(evt -> {
        if (!ttr.isEmpty()) {
            TableModel item = ttr.getItem();
            System.out.println("Clicked " + item); // TODO: replace
        }
    });
    return ttr;
});
```

Comment: Thank you so mych, This saves my day.

Comment: @John I noticed none of your questions have an accepted answer. If an answer solves your problem, consider accepting it.

Comment: Thanks for your advice.